# Get month from DATETIME in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to get extract the month from a `DATETIME` field in SQLite. `month(dateField)` does not work as well as `strftime('%m', dateStart)`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 56):

I don't understand, the response is in your question :

```
select strftime('%m', dateField) as Month ...
```

Comment: what if my format is MM/DD/YYYY instead of YYYY-MM-DD. that function does not work with the former format

Answer (score 24):

```
SELECT strftime('%m', datefield) FROM table
```

If you are searching the month name, text month names does not seems to be supported by the core distribution of SQLite

Comment: this is not correct if datefield is a native datetime type. You need to use strftime('%m', datetime(datefield, 'unixepoch')) as mentioned in another answer.

Answer (score 15):

I'm guessing you want to get the month as a string. Not the most friendly looking but you probably see the point. Just replace date('now') with your variable.

```
select case strftime('%m', date('now')) when '01' then 'January' when '02' then 'Febuary' when '03' then 'March' when '04' then 'April' when '05' then 'May' when '06' then 'June' when '07' then 'July' when '08' then 'August' when '09' then 'September' when '10' then 'October' when '11' then 'November' when '12' then 'December' else '' end
as month
```

Answer (score 13):

Try using the following:

```
select strftime('%m', datetime(datefield, 'unixepoch')) as month from table
```

Comment: Use this if you store your datetime values as integer in the database.

Answer (score 5):

This is a solution without all the case when statements. Hopefully it's helpful.

```
select substr('JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec', 1 + 3*strftime('%m', date('now')), -3)
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess `strftime('%m', dateStart)` is not working for you because dateStart variable is date/datetime type.

Then you must use:

```
strftime('%m', date(dateStart))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, even this returns None

Answer (score 1):

After all those years I think I figured out what was your problem.
You probably store your dates as strings.
This way when you search for data  from let's say May you should write sql like this:

`Select * from table where strftime('%m', datefield) = '05'`

It's important to write '05' and not '5'. Using '5' will give you zero results.

Answer (score 1):

SQLLite does not support monthnames, you need to use **substr(Date, 4, 2) as month** to get the months

> %sql select substr(date,4,2) as month from ;

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution that worked for me

```
MONTH_DICT={ "Jan" : '01', "Feb" : '02', "Mar" : '03', "Apr" : '04', "May" : '05', "Jun" : '06', "Jul" : '07', "Aug" : '08', "Sep" : '09', "Oct" : 10, "Nov" : 11, "Dec" : 12 }

self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM error_log WHERE strftime('%m',Date_column)=?",(MONTH_DICT[query_month],)) 

print('output:', self.cursor.fetchall())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select strftime('%Y', nextTime / 1000, 'unixepoch' ) as year, 
strftime('%m', nextTime / 1000, 'unixepoch' ) as month, 
count(*) as count from task group by year, month order by year, month;
```

nextTime is an integer which represent the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT. convert it to second unit by divide 1000, then the year and month can be extracted correctly. Read [sqlite datefunc](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) for more information.

Answer (score -5):

SELECT strftime('%m',datetime_col) as "Month" FROM table_name;

just replace 'datetime_col' with your datetime column