# How to filter rails model by month

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I want to get only those records of my model which belong to a particular month. I am using:

```
Order.where(created_at.strftime("%B"): "April")
```

where `created_at` is `DateTime`. `created_at.strftime("%B")` gives me month, but it does not work. Any alternative?

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably have to do this in plan SQL (not the activerecord DSL):

```
Order.where("strftime('%m', created_at) = ?", 'April')
```

[This uses the SQLite function to extract the month name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650480)

*(I haven't done Rails in a while, let me know if this doesn't work)*

Comment: You mean this - Order.where("strftime('%B', created_at) = ?", 'April'). Its not working

Comment: Order.where('extract(month from created_at)=?', 4) works but I want to search by month name not month number:-

Comment: It looks like [SQLite doesn't getting the month name](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) so you will probably have to map it to a number yourself.