# Rails group records by month using db query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord

Hi I am trying to find a simple way to expand my db query and group the records shown by month (Ideally I would like next month stored in "Next Page"). Is there a way to do this?

Current query

```
@submissions = Submission.where(:Desired_Location => current_agent.Company_Business_Location)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First [get month name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/650517/2570423) from your date field and then use `group` method to group by month

```
@submissions = Submission.where(:Desired_Location => current_agent.Company_Business_Location).group('strftime('%m', your_date_field)')
```

In your case I would suggest to group by year as well. In that case use this:

```
@submissions = Submission.where(:Desired_Location => current_agent.Company_Business_Location).group('strftime('%Y %m', your_date_field)')
```