# SQLLite strftime not reading column value

Tags: sql, sqlite

i have this in my Sqllite Database query, i want ...

```
select BoardingDate, strftime('%Y', date(BoardingDate)) from Hostels;
```

but in the output it renders `BoardingDate` correctly  and the output

```
BoardingDate        Month 
-------------------------
8/1/2007 0:00:00    null
3/1/2008 0:00:00    null
8/1/2008 0:00:00    null
3/1/2009 0:00:00    null
```

These is the current behaviour of the queries

```
 1. strftime('%Y', date('now'))         - outputs correctly
 2. strftime('%Y', date('2020-03-06'))  - it works also
 3. strftime('%Y', date(BoardingDate))  - Gives an error, it doesnt render at all.. 
 4. strftime('%Y', date(Hostels.BoardingDate))  - The same error...
 5. strftime('%Y', datetime(BoardingDate))  - Gives an error,
 6. strftime('%Y', datetime(Hostels.BoardingDate))  - doesnt work....
```

it prints the string, i dont know why. its working this way. 
i'm trying to calculate the date using the `julianday()` function but thats a longer approach
i'm just confused right now. thanks.

This is the error i get in the Message Panel

```
select BoardingDate, strftime('%Y',BoardingDate)
> no such column: BoardingDate
> Time: 0s
```

but the first column render correctly, but the function column returns this error
I tried following the solutions on these pages but to no avail

[get-month-from-datetime-in-sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650480/get-month-from-datetime-in-sqlite)

[sqlite-convert-string-to-date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428795/sqlite-convert-string-to-date)

i have tried other functions from this documentation [lang_datefunc.html](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)
but i still get the same error, when i try to pass a column reference as a parameter 
in a function

Comment: Change the format of your dates to YYYY-MM-DD and it will work.

Comment: @forpas but how do i convert `8/1/2007` to  `08/01/2017` within a query string? is there a way out? i'd be glad, if you could help with code. because i'm pulling from an already existing database.

Comment: A **very** complicated way with string functions.

Comment: What I suggest is to import the table in a database that is more flexible with dates and strings (like MySql) and do the conversions there and reimport back to SQLite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This "*how do i convert 8/1/2007 to 08/01/2017 within a query string*" won't help, since that is not a valid sqlite time string. And if MySql is not an option (which it is not for me), you would have to do the "*complicated string functions*". Which can be fairly straight forward once they're broken down.

The year is easy, it is `substr(adate,-12,4)` **assuming** the time component only has one digit for hour (-13 otherwise). And if you really only want the year (based on `'%Y'`) then bob's your uncle.

The month, likewise, is easy. Exploiting `CAST` which will convert text to an integer until the first non-numeric character, and using printf to 0 pad, this `printf('%02i',CAST (adate as int))` will give the month.

The day is a little more typing, because you need the part of the string *after* the first '/'. This `printf('%02i',CAST (substr(adate,instr(adate,'/') + 1) as int))` will do the trick.

All that's left is to concat them all together with some `-` in between, and voilà, it's a valid sqlite date.