# How to use strftime() function in sqlite for extracting Year where datetime is in a different format than what would normally work

Tags: sql, sqlite, strftime

While learning SQL in my course, I have used the function `YEAR(Start_Time) AS Year`

`Start_Time` is a column header. The date time example is in this format: `26/12/2017 09:00:00`
`YEAR()` function works in SQL.

However, when I went on SQLite (on DB Browser), the function is not working. I used the `strftime('%Y', 'Start_Time')`. I understand that strftime goes from left to right. Does anyone know what would be the equivalent function to `YEAR()` in sqlite with the date time format given above?

In SQL:

```
YEAR(Start_Time) AS Year
```

Answer:

> 2017

In sqlite:

```
YEAR(Start_Time)
```

Answer:

> function not recognized

```
strftime('%Y', 'Start_time')
```

Answer:

> function not recognized

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLLite strftime not reading column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60673844/sqllite-strftime-not-reading-column-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQlite is pretty different than other RDBMS : It doesn't have a date/time type.  You can only store  dates as numbers or text.

The function `strftime()` is able to extract date/time info from a date stored in a text column, but it only works if you respect the ISO8601 notation: **YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS** , which is not the case with your date.

If you want to extract the Year from it using `strftime()` , then you need to convert your date first

For your case, if you convert only the date part and not the time part, that works too.

Lets go:

```
SELECT  Start_Time, 
        (substr(Start_Time,7,4) || '-' || substr(Start_Time,4,2) || '-' || substr(Start_Time,1,2)) as dateconverted,
        strftime('%Y', (substr(Start_Time,7,4) || '-' || substr(Start_Time,4,2) || '-' || substr(Start_Time,1,2)) ) as year
FROM test;
```

Results

```
Start_Time              dateconverted     year
26/12/2017 09:00:00     2017-12-26        2017
```

If you want to avoid this mess, you just have to store your dates/times in the right format from the start, there's no other workaround.

Answer (score 2):

The way to do it it's your third choice. `strftime('%Y', 'time string')`. Make sure that time string it's a string in one of the accepted formats. You may see: (https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).