# SQLite count of order per hour

Tags: sql, sqlite, date, count, strftime

I only have SQLite on hand, and I want to calculate the count of order per hour per day with table with below columns:
orderID, order_datetime(yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss), location

```
SELECT 
   DATEPART('%H', order_datetime) as 'HOUR',
   COUNT(*) as 'ORDERPERHOUR'
   FROM vanorder
   GROUP BY DATEPART('%H', order_datetime);
```

I received error 'no such function: DATEPART', how can I achieve this in the world of sqlite? thanks.

Comment: Did you search? The documentation is [quite clear](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Comment: To clarify, do you want the count _for the same hour_ over _any day_, or a break-down per-hour _over all time_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SQLite's `strftime()` function with the correct syntax and format string:

```
SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H', order_datetime) hour,
       COUNT(*) ORDERPERHOUR
FROM vanorder
GROUP BY hour;
```

`strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H', order_datetime)` for a timestamp like `'2021-07-28 15:32:12'` will return `2021-07-28 15` which is what you want.

If you prefer to see values like `'2021-07-28 15:00:00'` then change to:

```
strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00', order_datetime)
```

Answer (score 2):

In SQLite, the equivalent uses `STRFTIME()`:

```
SELECT STRFTIME('%H', order_datetime) as hour
       COUNT(*) as ORDERPERHOUR
FROM vanorder
GROUP BY STRFTIME('%H', order_datetime);
```

If you are going to use SQLite, you should familiarize yourself with SQLite functions.

Comment: TIL that Sqlite doesn't have a `date`/`datetime` type - [and `STRFTIME` only works if you store dates in an ISO 8601 string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63691498/how-to-use-strftime-function-in-sqlite-for-extracting-year-where-datetime-is-i) (_wtf?!_) - so there's nothing automatically stopping `2021-02-31 61:99:61` from being stored. Eeep.

Comment: @dai . . . I am not going to defend SQLite's handling of date/time values.  But someone using SQLite should definitely be familiar with the functionality in that database.

Comment: First *familiarize yourself with SQLite functions*. Your code is syntactically and logically wrong. Who upvoted this?