# OUTPUT <NULL> WHEN SELECTING DATE FROM DATETIME - SQLITE

Tags: sqlite, date, datetime, null, strftime

I'm new to the SQL world and im going crazy trying to figure out how to SELECT date from a datetime field in SQLITE.

Example: value <11/11/2005 14:56>, i just want to select <11/11/2005> for EVERY ROW.

I tried strftime(), date(), CAST() and other functions but the output its always NULL.
For example i tried querying SELECT strftime('%d/%m/%Y' , columnname) AS date FROM tablename;
OUTPUT: "NULL" in every row

Can someone help me understand what im doing wrong and how can i fix it? Thank you!!!

Comment: What type is the column? If it's a datetime, does select column as date work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It always returns NULL because MM/DD/YYYY is not a valid sqlite [date format](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html). Treat the column as a string and use `substr` and `instr` to drop off the time portion. Something like (no guarantees, check the doc!)

`SELECT substr(columname,0,instr(columnname,' '))`

Re comment "*how to order by the date in descending order*"

This problem is a good argument (the best argument?) for storing the date in a sqlite date/time format. There is a strategy in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60673844/sqllite-strftime-not-reading-column-value/60679378#60679378) for converting MM/DD/YYYY to YYYY-MM-DD (which sorts dates correctly).

If it's not too late, it would be advisable to change the date storage to a valid sqlite date format. `strftime` can be used to present the date as desired, and sorting will be accurate.

Comment: Hello! Sorry that I bother you again but I was wondering if you know how to order by the date in descending order since I’m treating the column as a string. 

For example: I tried to ORDER BY datestring DESC and since it’s not in date format It didn’t output in the correct order.

Comment: Added into to answer.