# SQLite How can i create in sqlite a Table with 365 Rows and how can i insert the dates?

Tags: sqlite

"How can i create in sqlite a Table with 365 Rows and how can i insert the dates?"

For example:
Table MyTable

```
id  month   date
1   jan 2021-01-01
2   jan 2021-01-02
3   jan 2021-01-03
.
.
.
365 dec 2021-12-31
```

How can i create this automatically ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may reach this using recursive query

```
create table days as
with recursive qq as (
  select 1 id, 'jan' month, '2021-01-01' date_col union all
  select id + 1, substr('janfebmaraprmayjunjulaugsepoctnovdec', 1 + 3 * 
  strftime('%m', date(date_col, '+1 day')), -3), date(date_col, '+1 day')
   from qq
  where id <= 364
)
```

The monstrous line

```
substr('janfebmaraprmayjunjulaugsepoctnovdec', 1 + 3 * strftime('%m', date(date_col, '+1 day')), -3)
```

will cut the name of the month you need from the line based on the month number of the date. Ths one is needed because SQLIte seems to be [not able](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) to get month name from date.

There were [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650480/get-month-from-datetime-in-sqlite) of how one can get month names from date but it did not worked for me. Try those if you want

Here's an example on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=2b44078553f8bef4bca3bdae6ad6ad1b)

Comment: Thank you very much. it works fine :) I have another question. Is it possible to distribute the days in the month in calendar weeks ? or get the calendar weeks for the given month ? Example January: CW1: 04.01. 05.01 06.01 07.01 08.01 09.01 10.01

Comment: @emrepb sorry, not sure I am following you. Can you update the question with an example of desired output please?

Comment: @emrepb %W in `strftime()` will give the week of the year. See https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html